# Container of nav.logo move when i minimize screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I facing an issue here, when I minimize the screen to a smaller width, the container that contains the logo move down, and then the alignment all gone. but for the menu navigation bar it is able to maintain at the same location as the full size website.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {FaBars, FaTimes} from 'react-icons/fa'
import { Button } from './Button'
import './Navbar.css'
import {IconContext} from 'react-icons/lib'

function Navbar() {
    const [click,setClick]= useState(false);
    const [button,setButton]= useState(true)

    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
    const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false)

    const showButton = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 960){
            setButton(false)
        } else {
            setButton(true) 
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        showButton();
      }, []);

    window.addEventListener('resize',showButton);
    return (
        <>
        <IconContext.Provider value ={{color: "#fff"}}>
        <nav className='navbar'>
          <div className='navbar-container container'>
            <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
              <img src="/images/Logo-WHITE.png" alt="UOWKDU Logo" width="35%" height="75%"  className='navbar-icon' />
              
            </Link>
            <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
              {click ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
            </div>
            <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link
                  to='/services'
                  className='nav-links'
                  onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                >
                  Services
                </Link>
              </li>

              <li className='nav-btn'>
                {button ? (
                  <Link to='/sign-up' className='btn-link'>
                    <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>SIGN UP</Button>
                  </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link to='/sign-up' className='btn-link'>
                    <Button
                      buttonStyle='btn--outline'
                      buttonSize='btn--mobile'
                    >
                      SIGN UP
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                )}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        </IconContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}


export default Navbar
```

code this is just some part of the css file:

```css
.navbar {
    background: #1c2237;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;

  }
  
  .navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
  }
  
  .container {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    
  }
  
  .navbar-logo {
    color: #fff;
    justify-self: start;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;

  }

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .NavbarItems {
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .nav-menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      position: absolute;
      top: 80px;
      left: -100%;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
 .navbar-logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translate(25%, 50%);
      
    }
```

When the webpage is full size :
[image]

and when the webpage is minimize :
[image]

Comment: Missing HTML code. Please share enough code so we can reproduce the problem. Other than that, don't use `position: absolute` in the layout of the page unless you know exactly what you're doing - use padding and margin instead. Using rem as distances and sizes will make it simpler to create a responsive site. Then you can just change the font-size and everything will scale with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use `position: absolute;` in navigation. Try to avoid `display: flex;` too. Use `float: left;` & `overflow: hidden;` instead.

```
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden; /* Give a hidden overflow in navbar for background color visibility */
  background: #1c2237;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-container {
  float: left; 
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {

/* When display is 960px or lower, .navbar-container will be shown as block level 
element with 100% width */

.navbar-container {
  display: block;  
  width: 100%; 
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Use box-sizing if browser is adding a horizontal 
  scrollbar in the page. Otherwise, you can remove it */
}

.NavbarItems {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  top: 80px;
  left: -100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar-logo {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(25%, 50%);
}
```

Comment: Why not `display:flex`? Floats have lots of problems.

Comment: floats have problem but it's wise to use(I think) float in navigation. `display: flex;` sometimes mess with the navigation links(like padding, margin). But you can easily arrange your elements in float & control them in `@media screen`